# Magento 2 product content editor is trimming content after adding content

Tags: magento2, product, page-content

I am trying to add the content of my product. Written successfully the whole content but when I save editor is trimming my content after a specific length. Can someone review this how can I restrict to write the content before adding or increase the trimming length.

Comment: Charanjeet Singh, do you added the content into description field ? Make sure you don’t add to short description

Comment: Yes I am adding content in Description

Comment: my content is approx 65500 characters long

Comment: Check that field length

Comment: In which table can I find the length of this field

Comment: Yes I found this field in the `catalog_product_entity_text` table.